# Algorithm to calculate sum of elements of specific range in an array

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

We have an array `arr[0 . . . n-1]`. We should be able to Find the sum of elements from index l to r where `0 <= l <= r <= n-1`.

A simple solution is to run a loop from l to r and calculate sum of elements in given range. The operation takes `O(n)` time .

Another solution is to create another array and store sum from start to i at the ith index in this array. Sum of a given range can now be calculated in `O(1)` time.

In the first example the complexity is `O(n)` understood because it is traversing each element of the array. But in second solution how the complexity is `O(1)`.
Please help me to understand this.

Comment: O(1) + O(1) = O(1)

Comment: The second solution spends `O(n)` time on precalculating cumulative sums, so that `sum[i]` is the sum of all elements from `0` to `i`. To find the sum of elements between indices `i` and `j`, you only need to fetch `sum[i]` and `sum[j]`, and subtract them. Accessing array items is `O(1)`, since it involves only a single read from a known location, and `2 * O(1)` is still `O(1)`, as @Henk wrote above.

Comment: Thank you all for the reply. Understood the concept now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second solution consists of a preprocessing step with `O(n)` complexity and calculating `sum[r] - sum[l-1]` that is obviously `O(1)`. The overall complexity is `O(n)`.

The difference between these solutions is the time complexity of the query part. The first solution has `O(n)` query, second - `O(1)`. And if we have `m` range queries then the complexity of the first approach would be `O(n*m)`, and complexity of the second - `O(n+m)` that is much better.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Understood the concept now.

Answer (score 0):

The complexity mentioned is about answering query. In first case, you are iterating through `l` to `r` which makes it `O(n)`, but in second case, `sum[l] = arr[0] + ... + arr[l]` and `sum[r] = arr[0]+ ... +arr[r]`. To get the sum of the elements in the range [l,r] you have to do `sum[r]-sum[l-1]` where **{l>0}**, which is just a single operation. That's why the complexity in second case is `O(1)`